# How to verify the reCAPTCHA (v3) request on server side?

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

As a first step to avoid receiving spam I managed to implement reCAPTCHA (v3) on client side (see Javascript and HTML-form). Without result yet because I still do receive spam. After reading several posts on the web I found out that I also have to implement it on server side. However, for me it is unclear how to integrate [this](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) in my PHP-script (sendmail.php). It does not seem to work and I don't know how to find the root cause / test. Do you know how to verify the reCAPTCHA (v3) request on server side?

**Javascript**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

<script>
      function onSubmit(token) {
        document.getElementById("contact-form").submit();
       }
</script>
```

**HTML-form**

```
<div>
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="sendmail.php" role="form">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Naam" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
    <textarea rows="6" placeholder="Bericht" class="form-control" name="description" id="description"></textarea>   

    <div id="cf-submit">
        <input  type="submit" 
                id="contact-submit" 
                class="btn btn-transparent g-recaptcha"  
                data-sitekey="public key" 
                data-action='submit'
                value="Verzend"
                data-badge="inline"
        >
    </div>

</form> </div>
```

**PHP (sendmail.php)**

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    
    $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $recaptcha_secret = 'SECRET_KEY';
    $recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    
    $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response);
    $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha, true);
    
    if ($recaptcha['success'] == 1 AND $recaptcha['score'] >= 0.5 AND $recaptcha['action'] == "submit")
    {
        $email_to =   'mail@mail.com'; //the address to which the email will be sent
        $name     =   $_POST['name'];  
        $email    =   $_POST['email'];
        $subject  =   $_POST['name'];
        $message  =   $_POST['description'];

        $headers  = "From: $email\r\n";
        $headers  = "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
    
        if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers))
        {
            echo 'sent';      
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'failed';   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}?>
```

Comment: You need to make an HTTP request to the API endpoint, and then dependent on the result either send your mail, or not. If you don't know how to make HTTP requests via PHP, then that would be your first thing to research now.

Comment: @Cbroe after some research I did update my PHP-script (sendmail.php). However, still without result. Do you have any idea if I am in the right direction?

Comment: Did `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` contain a value? What response did you get for the HTTP request to the verify endpoint?

Comment: @Cbroe where can I see what the response of the HTTP request is?

Comment: Make a `var_dump` of the result of the `file_get_contents` call.